# How to redirect page if the url is incorrect?

Tags: php, .htaccess

For example if after question mark there is another word, it redirects to home page.
After question mark there can be only the word `lang=hy` or `lang=ru` or `lang=en`:

```
https://it-center.am/?lang=hy
```

But otherwise it should redirect to home page. For example there can not be url like this:

```
https://it-center.am/?lang=hyyy
```

Should I change something in `.htaccess`?

Here is code of languages.php

```
define('LANGUAGE_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/language/", false);
define('TEMPLATE_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/", false);

$languages = [
    "hy",
    "ru",
    "en",
];

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']) OR !isset($_GET['lang']))
{
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $languages[0];
    $language = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else {
    $language = $_GET['lang'];

}
include_once(LANGUAGE_DIR . $language . '.php');

$valid = array("en", "ru", "hy");
    if (!in_array($_GET["lang"], $valid)) {
    header("Location /index.php?lang=hy");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Eh, what does this mean? `if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']) OR !isset($_GET['lang']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(?:hy|ru|en)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://it-center.am/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, I would say you need to handle it using `.php`. I'll start by defining a list of valid codes and then if the request doesn't match it, I'll redirect it.

```
$valid = array("en", "ru", "hy");
if (!in_array($_GET["lang"], $valid)) {
  header("Location: ./?lang=en");
  die();
}
```

Comment: I used your code, but it does not redirect me to index.php

Comment: @hasratyan Where is it redirecting then? Change this line to `header("Location /index.php");`

Comment: Did it. Please look. Now it brings 500 internal error

Comment: @hasratyan Sorry, there should be a `:` after `Location`.

Comment: @hasratyan Change to this: `header("Location: /index.php");`

Comment: @hasratyan That's fine. Glad that you got a solution. Merry Christmas.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Merry Christmas.

Comment: @hasratyan Welcome! `:)`